# Idiom or word for the accessing a thing that is far away

Tags: idiom-requests

Imagine that something is physically located very far from me, but I have some kind of mediator that allows me to reach it, touch it, communicate with it. The example is Skype that allows to get in touch with the loved ones. Or google start page allows to communicate with the most powerful search engine ever. 
What would be a word or idiom(which does not stick to technical terms) for such a mediator?

Comment: I'd call it "remote access".

Comment: @HotLicks 'remote access' is the activity facilitated by the noun the OP requests, but it seems to me they are looking for a generic description of the facilitating actor- 'Portal' would be my suggestion, but alas it is not close enough to be a good answer, particularly as it has taken on a specific meaning in web language

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a ***medium*** to me. See meaning 2b [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/medium):

> a channel or system of communication, information, or entertainment

Comment: And the plural is *media*.

Answer (score 0):

In the title, you ask for an idiom describing the action of accessing the faraway thing.  For that, I'd suggest ***reach out and touch someone***.  This was originally an [advertising slogan for a telephone company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N._W._Ayer_%26_Son#AT.26T), but it was so successful that it entered into popular culture, and has been applied to things as unrelated to placing a phone call as [shooting someone](http://thefiringline.com/forums/showthread.php?t=411932).

Answer (score -1):

There is an idiom for something that is exceptionally or relatively far away.

We say that some location is *hard to get to* (but not inaccessible) by saying

> It's in BFE.

BFE is an acronym; E is a country, B is a body-part and F is a verb.

If I were writing some function or procedure like the one you are describing I'd could call it `accessBFE();`.

**update** I tried to bring an original idea and some levity to the table in my answer. I carefully thought it out, formatted it and self-edited it to make my answer as clear & concise as I could.

Is it offensive? this downvote really hurt my rep; so constructive criticism would be appreciated. Or an upvote if you "get it" or "think it's a good idea" or you *"know that it is factually a correct answer."*

Maybe one of you would like to bring me back up to zero at least?
Was some manner of disrespect gleaned from my answer or sarcasm? while I do joke, I never intentionally disrespect, attempt to be *UN*clear and I *never* use sarcasm - that's college English 101.

**I made no changes to the answer (other than the prose following "update"). It stands until I stand corrected.** -cw